# Chosen with Ajax in Classic Asp

Tags: ajax, asp-classic, jquery-chosen

I'm new to Ajax and Chosen so please bear with me. I'm trying to reload a second select box based on the selection of the first one. All of my select boxes are using the Chosen plugin.

First, this is my JQuery function for chosen.

```
$(function(){

   $('.TeacherName').chosen({                 max_selected_options: 1, placeholder_text_multiple: "Select A Teacher"});

 $('.Schools')    .chosen({                 max_selected_options: 1, placeholder_text_multiple: "Select A School" });

});
</script>
```

Next I load the two boxes from a record-set.

```
<select class="Schools" name="Schools" id="schoolDrop" style="max-width:210px;" multiple="multiple"  onchange="getLocation(this.value);">

                        <% while not SchoolList.eof%>
                            <option value="<%=SchoolList("SCHOOL_NUMBER")%>"><%=SchoolList("NAME")%> </option>
                        <%SchoolList.MoveNext
                        wend%>

</select>   

<select class="TeacherName" name="TeacherName" id="TeacherName" multiple="multiple"style="max-width:150px;">
                    <option value="0"></option>

                    <%while not TeacherList.eof%>
                        <option value="<%=TeacherList("DCID")%>"</option>
                        <%TeacherList.MoveNext
                    wend%>

</select>
```

As you can see I call the Ajax function in an onchange event in the Schools select box.

Next is my Ajax Function.

```
function getLocation(schoolId) 
{       
    var strURL="SetTeacherAjax.asp?school="+schoolId;

    var req = getXMLHTTP();

    if (req) 
    {
        req.onreadystatechange = function() 
        {
            if (req.readyState == 4) 
            {
                // only if "OK"
                if (req.status == 200) 
                {                   
                    document.getElementById('TeacherName').innerHTML=req.responseText;              
                } else 
                {
                    alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
                }
            }               
        }           
        req.open("GET", strURL, true);
        req.send(null);
    }       
}//End of Function getLocation
```

The ajax works if I remove the class selector from the TeacherName drop down.

Comment: When I added the < this page was completely leaving out the whole select statement.

Comment: You need to indent code by 4 spaces for it to render as code on this site.  There is a button marked {} that does it for selected text.

Comment: Thanks. I'll keep that in mind for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

I've figure this out, so I'll post it as it may help someone else. I needed to add an update statement for Chosen plugin.

```
enter code here                 if (req.status == 200) 
                {                   
                    document.getElementById('TeacherName').innerHTML=req.responseText;  
                    $('#TeacherName').trigger('chosen:updated');                                    
                } else 
                {
                    alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
                }
```

Once I added the

`$('#TeacherName').trigger('chosen:updated');`

it worked.